# Does minimumm spanning tree always include the node with highest degree?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, network-analysis

I want to know why the distances between nodes in a minimum spanning tree seems to be rooted to the node with highest degree.

A bit of context here:

I have spatial explicit weighted network that describes the physical growth pattern of a fungal colony. Most of the nodes in this network have either degree = 1 or degree =3 (degree=2 is not possible because of biological reasons). Degree >4 are not possible except for only one (and only one) case: the center of the colony, where all edges orginally radiate.

Using the observed network, I obtained the MST (taking into account edge weights. BTW I using the mst function in igraph for R). I did this because I wanted to know how much the fungal colony differs from a MST pattern. However, I noticed that the resulting MST is essentially made up of the shortests paths between the center of the colony (that is, the only node with degree > 4) and any other node in the network. I am a biologist diving into network science, so I am now curious why is that so? why I do not get a shorthest path that does not include the node with hightest degree in the MST?

Comment: An MST will contain all nodes in the graph, but not necessarily all edges. To be an MST the weights of the *edges* used to connect all of the nodes should be the minimum.

Comment: That´s right! It includes all nodes. Thanks! I am now digesting why, then, the edges kept by the MST are exactly the same ones as if I calculate the shortest path (resistance based) from the center to any other node.

Comment: It's possible there are many equal-weight MSTs, and the algorithm just happened to pick this one. It's easy to construct an edge-weighted graph in which no MST uses more than a single edge incident on the highest-degree node (you can do this with just 5 vertices).

Comment: Thanks! I will play around with some simple networks to check what the possible MST result. I found this curious because for the MST, I use the Prim algorithm while for calculating shortest paths I use the Dijkstra algorithm.